# Is it ok to think in entangled particles as one in function of the other?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

As I read in this question: [If two particles are entangled and you collapse the wave function of one of the particles. Does the other particle collapse as well?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317535/if-two-particles-are-entangled-and-you-collapse-the-wave-function-of-one-of-the) 
Two entangled particles share the same wave function that describes the entire quantum system.
My question is, if you think in the individual particles, say A and B, is it OK to think that B = F(A) where F would be the "correlation" between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In quantum mechanics if two particles are entangled you can't talk about the state of each of them individually. Objects in quantum mechanics are described by vectors in a Hilbert space, and using bra-ket notation we have an entangled state as follows:

$$\left | \Psi \right>_{AB} = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \left ( \left | 0 \right>_A \left|0\right>_B+\left | 1 \right>_A \left|1\right>_B\right)$$

A state is not entangled if and only if you can write it as a "product state":

$$\left| \Psi \right>_{AB}= \left| \psi\right>_A \left|\phi\right>_B$$

Only in this case can you talk about the state of a single subsystem (or particle).